# Callback from native Java to Unity's C# script has some weird (latency?) issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface, clr

I'm developing a Unity plugin that uses BLE to communicate with some device. I have implementation for both Windows (using P/Invoke to this device's SDK) and Android, which uses Unity's helper classes for interfacing with the JVM. The device's SDK in Java has a callback for incoming new data, the callback looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDeviceData(BluetoothDevice device, byte[] data) {

}
```

I've implemented a class that inherits Unity's `AndroidJavaProxy` to register a callback handler from the C# side:

```
class Callbacks : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> IncomingMessages { get; private set; }

    public Callbacks()
        : base("com.example.sdk.SdkCallbacks")
    {
        IncomingMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
    }

    void onDeviceData(AndroidJavaObject device, byte[] data)
    {
        IncomingMessages.Enqueue(data);
    }
}
```

I have a script in the scene that deques this data in the `Update()` function like so:

```
while (!_device.IncomingMessages.IsEmpty)
{
    byte[] data;

    if (_device.IncomingMessages.TryDequeue(out data))
    {
        // do something with the data
    }
}
```

In my specific case I'm using the data coming from the device to move a point on the screen (think "wireless mouse").

That works pretty well, until I need to get high-rate data from the device (About ~60 callbacks per second with the `data` parameter containing an array of ~30 bytes). At first everything looks okay, but after a few seconds the point starts to lag heavily behind the actual input from the device, and the lag only gets bigger with time.

I've tried checking if the `IncomingMessages` queue is getting too big which would mean the producer outpace the consumer by a lot, causing an ever-increasing delay, but that was not the case, `IncomingMessages.Count` always shows 0-2.

This does not happen when running the code on Windows and using the device's SDK from a regular Android app also works well.

Can this be a marshaling overhead between the JNI and the CLR runtimes? Or something similar?

If so, is there anything I can do about it? I know Unity has another way of communicating between native and the scripting runtime with `UnitySendMessage` but I'm not sure if that won't have the same problem.

Comment: "Can this be a marshaling overhead between the JNI and the CLR runtimes?" that cannot be the case, there's no CLR running, Unity transforms C# code into native code, it doesn't use .NET

Comment: Instead of the functioning being in update, can you not do the while loop inside a coroutine?

Comment: @BugFinder Why would that help? The queue usually contains between 0-2 entries, so it doesn't block the main loop for long. I only care about the latest piece of data in that queue. If I get more than one piece of data in a frame, I don't mind skipping all of them and only use apply the last.

Comment: but are you getting the last, or are you getting the first of the batch? because a while loop in the update method can slow down updates it may lead to the lag look

Comment: @BugFinder I would get the last. Currently after dequeuing I basically do something like this (pseudo code): `_point.position = ParseData(data)`. The reason I use a queue and not just a shared variable locked by a mutex is because I might receive other types of data packets (control/error etc) which I need no to miss. Maybe I should've clarified this a bit more in the post.